# What is "<>" when defining a method?

Tags: c#, generics, asynchronous

So I know a bit about generic classes and methods.
but still don't get the syntax when I see it like this.

```
private async Task<JsonValue> GetJsonDoc(string url)
```

Comment: I guess your confusion comes from the fact, that `await GetJsonDoc(someUrl)` will return `JsonValue`, not `Task<JsonValue>` - that's a specialty of async/await syntax.

Comment: No @Fildor, I was confused about the async keyword and how it affects syntax in method definition.

Comment: Actually it's an implementation detail. The whole effect *on the method defintion* is that it is there. The effect on method *body* is that you can use `await` inside the method and you return the type that's inside "<>" of the Task. But that's specific to TAP and async/await, not generics in general.

Answer (score 3):

It defines the type stored, used or returned by the generic type (in this case `Task`). So in this the method `GetJsonDoc` returns a `Task`, which will return a `JsonValue` when it runs and completes.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `<JsonValue>` is the Type that the task will return. For example, if you had `<Int32>` here instead, your task would return an integer value.

Good source of reading on this [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189374/The-Basics-of-Task-Parallelism-via-C).

A very basic example that returns a string value:

```
private static async Task<string> MyNewTask()
    {
        int timer;

        for (timer = 0; timer < 10; timer++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(timer);
        }

        return "Time left = " + timer;
    }
```

You can see from the example above that a string value is returned as a result of running the task.

In your example above, the task takes a string as a parameter, and returns a JsonValue type object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This indicate a "Generic" class.

Generics are used when a class needs to contain objects of another class.

For example a `List<string>` is a list object that contains string objects.

`Task<JsonValue>` is a `Task` where the `Result` property is of type `JsonValue`.

Before generics where introduced the functionality was implemented by storing references of type "object". This can be seen in the old collection classes (so `List` instead of `List<T>`).

There are two main drawbacks solved by generics compared to simply storing objects:

1. No need to cast. If Task had not been generic, you would have to use (JsonDoc)Task.Result. Besides being tedious to type the compiler can't check the type for it making it error prone and hard to refactor.
2. Performance for value types. While basic types like `int`, `string`, etc can be represented by `object` it's not actually how they are represented in memory. So when they are converted to or from `object` it takes processing time and memory. This is referred to as "boxing" and "unboxing".

In general you do not need to create your own generic classes when you are just doing basic programming - you just use the ones written by others. If you make classes that will be used by other programmers it can be a useful skill.